# Can Azure web app use SSO to connect to on-premise application

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-webapps

I got a customer that has several on premises services, specifically a SMTP Server and a Sharepoint Server. Both these servers are integrated with and AD Directory that is federated with Azure AD.

My question is, if the Web API published on Azure Web App is authenticated against this Azure AD, can the use the user invoke the SMTP server impersonating the web api caller?

Answer (score 0):

The SSO solves the authentication part. But in order to access resources on your customer site, it needs a VPN to be able to reach his servers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: I do have a VPN but can web app use the identity of the caller to invoke a thid party API?.